# Speed - embedding python in c++ or extending python with c++

Tags: c++, python, embedding, extending

I have some big mysql databases with data for calculations and some parts where I need to get data from external websites.

I used python to do the whole thing until now, but what shall I say: its not a speedster.

Now I'm thinking about mixing Python with C++ using Boost::Python and Python C API.

The question I've got now is: what is the better way to get some speed. 
Shall I extend python with some c++ code or shall I embedd python code into a c++ programm?

I will get fore sure some speed increment using c++ code for the calculating parts and I think that calling the Python interpreter inside of an C-application will not be better, because the python interpreter will run the whole time. And I must wrap things python-libraries like mysqldb or urllib3 to have a nice way to work inside c++.

So what whould you suggest is the better way to go: extending or embedding?
( I love the python language, but I'm also familiar with c++ and respect it for speed )

Update:
So I switched some parts from python to c++ and used multi threading (real one) in my c modules and my programm now needs instead of 7 hours 30 minutes :))))

Comment: Are you sure the delay is in the execution of the python code?  Generally if you are dealing with external data or databases, the speed bottleneck (thousand to one) is there.

I would VERIFY that it is the python code.  Then see if `cython` or `psyco` would help you out!

Comment: If you need to get data from external websites, your programming language will certainly not be the bottleneck. I'm not sure you're going down the correct road here. Why not just stick with Python? edit: @gahooa beat me :)

Comment: the scripts run on a dedicated server aswell as the databases. the only thing that is really external are the websites and webservices that need to be downloaded and parsed. downloading speed wont be increased, but parsing time could be aswell as the calculating time of the whole data. hope I understood you right.

Comment: @DavidTitarenco well the part with the websites are like 1-2 % what my program has to do. 1. if some new data is available I have to download it, parse it, and put it in the database. 2. checking every hour of new data is available. so this is not so much the speed problem.

Comment: -1 This is a complete non-question, for two reasons: 1) Your bottleneck is almost certainly not the CPU in the use-cases you've described. 2) If embedding Python into C++ is going to cause the Python code to be interpreted, then **obviously** writing your bottleneck code in C++ and calling that from Python is going to be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, I agree with the first two answers. Anything coming from disk or across a network connection is likely to be a bigger bottleneck than the application.

All the research of the last 50 years indicates that people often have inaccurate intuition about system performance issues. So IMHO, you really need to gather some evidence, by measuring what is actually happening, then chose a solution based on that evidence.

To try to confirm what is causing the slow performance, measure the system and user time of your application (e.g `time python prog.py`), and measure the load on the machine.

It the application is maxing-out the CPU, and most of that time is spent in the application (user time), then there may be a case for using a more effective technology for the application.

But if the CPU is not maxed, or the application spends most of its time in the system (system time), and not in the application (user time), then it is unlikely that changing the application programming technology will help significantly. (This is an example of Amdahl's Law http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)

You may also need to measure the performance of your database server, and maybe network connection, to identify the source of the bottle neck, but start with the easiest part.

Comment: nice I didn't know that there was something like "time xxxx" thank you :) and I guess you are right with the measuring. but rewriting some parts in c++ wont be a disadvantage and also help me to improve my cross-language-skills. And than I can also measure the time and see if it helped me or not.

Comment: If you have access to a Mac, Solaris, or FreeBSD box, you might want to investigate using DTrace. You can get 'end to end', i,e, through the kernel, network drivers and file system, performance measurements using it. You might also want to investigate ways to profile Python, for example http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, in your case it makes no sense to embed Python in C++, while the reverse could be beneficial.

In most of programs, the performance problems are very localized, which means that you should rewrite the problematic code in C++ only where it makes sense, leaving Python for the rest.

This gives you the best of both world: the speed of C++ where you need it, the ease of use and flexibility of Python everywhere else. What is also great is that you can do this process step by step, replacing the slow code paths by the by, leaving you always with the whole application in an usable (and testable!) state.

The reverse wouldn't make sense: you'd have to rewrite almost all the code, sacrificing the flexibility of the Python structure.

Still, as always when talking about performance, before acting *measure*: if your bottleneck is not CPU/memory bound switching to C++ isn't likely to produce much advantages.

Comment: thats what I thought as well, but I dont know for sure, cos I never did this both before :)